# Modelling entities with states in sql where the entity has more attributes as it advances a state (Hibernate)

Tags: sql, hibernate, state

I need to be able to model a single entity that can be in different states. The issue is that in each state the entity has more fields attributed to it.

In my case I have a Match entity which has the states "pending", "ready", "running" and "finished". A pending match hold the date and time the match is to commence and what server it will be hosted on, a ready match holds the teams who will be competing in the match, a running match holds the live scores of the match as it's running and the finished match will hold the time the match finished and the winner.

Summarising, the match entity goes through a sort of pipeline where at different stages, new fields are added to it.

One approach is to have one big Match table with all the fields for all states that get filled in as the match advances a state. This would mean the table would have many null values, but they would all eventually get filled by the time the match is in its final state.

Another is to have a table for each of the matches stage (PendingMatch, ReadyMatch, RunningMatch... etc.) with only the fields relevant to each stage. Since i'm using hibernate, each state would have its own class so when a match is loaded you can only access the fields relevant to that state. The issue with this method however is that I would be repeating columns across tables and in order to advance the matches state, I would have to pop it from its current table and insert it into the next table with the new data for that state.

Neither solution seems ideal, but I cant see any other way of modelling this.
I'm sure this is a common problem, but since the exact description of the is such a mouthful its very difficult to find anything on it!

If anyone could explain which approach is best or perhaps a totally new approach that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Yepadee

p.s. I'm using hibernate ORM tool to model this

Comment: What actually is the question ? Note that if the question is "which way is better and why" you can expect votes for closing this question as "Primarily opinion based".

Comment: I've updated the post to make the question more obvious. Essentially I'd like to find out if there's an established way/"design pattern" for doing something like this since it seems like something quite common.